# Need to read a file and use results as named variables in a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the following output file from a venn program.

```
[1, 2],106
[1, 3],2556
[2, 3],5207
[1, 2, 3],232
[2],7566
[3],8840
[1],5320
```

I need a command to get each line result number as variable argument in a script like this:

```
$area1=here it must come the results after [1],
$area2=here it must come the results after [2],
$area3=here it must come the results after [3],
$n12=here it must come the results after [1, 2],
$n13=here it must come the results after [1, 3],
$n23=here it must come the results after [2, 3],
$n123=here it must come the results after [1, 2, 3],
```

these results will then be used in the script below to draw a venn diagram.

```
cat << catfile >> $prefix1-VennDiagram.R
library(VennDiagram);
venn.diagram(
    x = list(
        "$sample1" = c(1:$area1, $(($area1+1)):$(($area1+$n12)), $(($area1+$n12+1)):$(($area1+$n12+$n123)), $(($area1+$n12+$n123+1)):$(($area1+$n12+$n123+$n13))),
        "$sample2" = c($(($area1+$n12+$n123+$n13+1)):$(($area1+$n12+$n123+$n13+$area2)), $(($area1+1)):$(($area1+$n12)), $(($area1+$n12+1)):$(($area1+$n12+$n123)), $(($area1+$n12+$n123+$n13+$area2+1)):$(($area1+$n12+$n123+$n13+$area2+$n23))),
        "$sample3" = c($(($area1+$n12+$n123+$n13+$area2+$n23+1)):$(($area1+$n12+$n123+$n13+$area2+$n23+$area3)),  $(($area1+$n12+1)):$(($area1+$n12+$n123)), $(($area1+$n12+$n123+1)):$(($area1+$n12+$n123+$n13)), $(($area1+$n12+$n123+$n13+$area2+1)):$(($area1+$n12+$n123+$n13+$area2+$n23)))
        ),
    filename = "$prefix1-VennDiagram.tiff",
    col = "transparent",
    fill = c("red", "blue", "green"),
    alpha = 0.5,
    label.col = c("darkred", "white", "darkblue", "white", "white", "white", "darkgreen"),
    cex = 2.5,
    fontfamily = "arial",
    fontface = "bold",
    cat.default.pos = "text",
    cat.col = c("darkred", "darkblue", "darkgreen"),
    cat.cex = 2.0,
    cat.fontfamily = "arial",
    cat.fontface = "italic",
    cat.dist = c(0.06, 0.06, 0.03),
    cat.pos = 0
    );
catfile

Rscript $prefix1-VennDiagram.R
exit
```

Comment: Since you'll be using `R` anyway, why don't you read and parse the file in `R`?

Comment: the Rscript is inside in a shell script... I want to keep the variables though

Comment: What `bash` version are you using?

Comment: 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In BASH it would be convenient to store the values in an associative array first and then assign them to the correct variables.

Suppose the output of `venn` is stored in `venn.txt`
then the following code could parse it for you

```
declare -A venn
while read line ; do 
   key=$(echo "$line" | sed 's/^\(\[[^]]*\]\).*/\1/') 
   value=$(echo "$line" | sed 's/^\[[^]]*\],\(.*\)/\1/') 
   if [ -n "$key" ] ; then # This check is necessary 
                           # to protect against empty lines
     venn["$key"]="$value" ; 
   fi 
done <<< "$( cat venn.txt )"
```

Now you could extract the variables from the array in your script

```
area1=${venn["[1]"]}
area2=${venn["[2]"]}
area3=${venn["[3]"]}
n12=${venn["[1, 2]"]}
n13=${venn["[1, 3]"]}
n23=${venn["[2, 3]"]}
n123=${venn["[1, 2, 3]"]}
```

In the parsing code we use Here String `<<<word` syntax in order to have the loop executed in the same shell instance as the rest of the code, so that the changes to the associative array were recorded.

Comment: I tried to run but got the following error message: draw-venn.sh: 3: draw-venn.sh: declare: not found
draw-venn.sh: 11: draw-venn.sh: Syntax error: redirection unexpected

Comment: @AndréMarques Check that you are not using `sh` instead of `bash`

Comment: Indeed I was using sh instead of bash! Great! It worked very nicely, just as expected. Many thanks @DmitriChubarov

Comment: @AndréMarques great to hear that. If you like a solution you can vote it up and/or accept it and get a nice badge in your profile and/or a few reputation points.